# sometimes python select.select gives empty string

Tags: python, select, ssh, paramiko

I have written code to read output from ssh when command is executed below is sample code

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(cmd)
channel = stdout.channel
stdin.close()
channel.shutdown_write()
stdout_chunks=[]
exit_status = 1
#stdout_chunks.append(stdout.channel.recv(len(stdout.channel.in_buffer)))
stdout_chunks.append(stdout.channel.recv(1024))
#or channel.recv_ready() or channel.recv_stderr_ready()
while not channel.closed or channel.recv_ready() or channel.recv_stderr_ready():
    readq, _, _ = select.select([stdout.channel], [], [], timeout)
for c in readq:
        if c.recv_ready(): 
            stdout_chunks.append(stdout.channel.recv(512))
            got_chunk = True
            print stdout_chunks[-1]

        if c.recv_stderr_ready():
            print stderr.channel.recv_stderr(512)
            got_chunk = True

    if not got_chunk and stdout.channel.exit_status_ready() and not stderr.channel.recv_stderr_ready() and not stdout.channel.recv_ready(): 
        stdout.channel.shutdown_read()
        stdout.channel.close()
        stdout.channel.recv_exit_status()
        break
```

But when i print readq sometimes i get empty string like `[]` because of that my execution doesn't proceed further. How to handle this kind of scenario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry, but the question is not clear. If your readq has no members, then the for loop is not executed at all (and no exception is raised). In this case, that is all code below the for loop. Is that the answer to the question you are asking?

Comment: select always return whether a file has grown since it was last read then how come it returns empty list?